# error - "no matching function for call to 'show2D'" while trying to call the function; why this error?

Tags: c++

In the code that I have attached here, I have written the function called "show2D" and then I want to run this function inline 21 but it is showing an error there saying "no matching function for call to 'show2D'"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void show2D(int variable[][20]){
    int answer[4000];
    int n=0;
    for (int i=0; i<20;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<20;j++){
            if (variable[i][j]%2==1){
              answer[n]=variable[i][j];
              n++;
            }
        }
    }   
}
int main() {
   int trailarr[2][2];
   trailarr[0][0] = 0;
   trailarr[0][1] = 1;
   trailarr[1][0] = 2;
   trailarr[1][1] = 3;
   show2D(trailarr);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typo? `int trailarr[2][2];` should be `int trailarr[2][20];`.

Comment: `show2D` takes a 2D int array with a variable number of rows and 20 columns (although the code is written so that it's only valid when `variable` has 20 rows). `trailarr` is a 2D int array with 2 rows and 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Because `trailarr` is a `[2][2]` array and `show2D` expects an array of size `variable[][20]`. So the linker does not find any function called `show2D` that can accept a `[2][2]` array.

Comment: Declare `trailarr`as a `[20][20]` array: `int trailarr[20][20]`. The use `for` loops to initialize the values

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thank you.